# Dataset in ASP.NET 4 and ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, sql

What is the purpose of the Dataset in ASP.NET 4 and ASP.NET 4.5? What makes it a better option than using a DataReader / GridView combination?

My interest is only in the DataSet, when to use it, why, and perhaps how to use it.

One of the reasons I am looking for an adequate explanation is because Microsoft is still requiring knowledge of the DataSet in their Certification requirements (see [Accessing Data with Microsoft .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-516&locale=en-us#tab2)).

I am not sure, but it seems that they have not abandoned the DataSet in ASP.NET 4 as many articles imply, but please correct me if my assumption is incorrect. You'll obviouslly need to point me to where Microsoft actually says that we should only use the DataSet / ASP.NET in the rare scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did DataSets in the MCTS: ADO.NET 3.5 exam. Basically, they explain that it's useful to use DataTables and DataSets because you can work with them independently without the need for a constant connection to the database.

You can populate them via the database, then work with them in memory. They are "*Active Disconnected Objects*". After working with them in memory, you can then save them back to the database with any changes you have made.

The typical use case is, you read data from your database & populate the dataset/datatables. You then bind this to a GridView and let the user add/edit/delete to it and then you propagate the changes back to the database.

**EDIT: For a truly balanced explanation of the pros & cons of DataSets, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163751.aspx**

Comment: Yes, I understand the basic use for DataSets, in fact I've used them myself, but I am really asking whether the DataSet is still useful since Microsoft still believes in it. Are there any DataSet believers out there, or is it dead, and why?

Comment: To be honest, I think you'd struggle to find someone who is a fan of DataSets. They're one of the many things throughout the Microsoft exams that are largely useless/superseded by other things.

Comment: I used the certification issue to point out that Microsoft seems to still believe in the DataSet, but you're correct, I cannot find a single DataSet fan, yet I cannot help but suspect that many are still using it, and I would like to know in what scenarios it would be very useful, excluding the very basic scenarios of cause.

Comment: @user1361906 here's a good MSDN magazine article outlining when to use them :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163751.aspx

Comment: mattytommo, the MSDN magazine article is the first truly balanced explanation regarding the DataSet that I've seen since asking this question on other sites a while back, well done.

Comment: If at first you don't succeed, check MSDN :). If I was the answer to your question, click the white tick next to my answer :)

Comment: @mattytommo: went ahead and did that for you :)

Comment: Is there a way I can highlight the MSDN article, since that is the answer I support?

Comment: @user1361906 I have edited my post to include the MSDN article link :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

I stopped using Datasets, as they are not very usefull in web servers and other disconnected environment (were the DataSet can't be linked to the Database directly).

If it's part of certification and you need the certification (why ?) than you need to study...

I think you better invest time in Entity Framework as an ORM tool....

Dataset is useful for speedy development in a client-server connected app. easy CRUD operations ect.

Comment: Why are the certifications a bad thing? :)

Comment: I am not doing any certifications, used it to point out that Microsoft still believes in DataSet / ASP.NET.

Comment: Ms certification would always be one step behind, and in the certification they sometimes needs to teach you something that was a common usage before, and even if not recommended now, you still need to know it.